# how to add percentage value to legend field in pie chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, chart.js

I am using chart.js for developing pie chart. My chart works fine all i need to do is show the percentage at the Legend section for my pie chart. 
Please refer to the following image: [[image: Chart 1]

I want to show percentage in Legend section (heighlited section).
How can I add the percentage at the legent in pie chart? Or also is it possible to have some chart like below with chart.js:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the legendTemplate attribute, to something like this:

```
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%> : <%=datasets[i].points[datasets[i].points.length-1].value%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```